fix top appbar color when scrolling after implementing edge to edge
After adding top.inset to top appbar the statusbar has some kind of lag when scrolling and it changes colors. How can I solve this?
 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    enableEdgeToEdge(SystemBarStyle.auto(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT))

    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.toolbar)) { v, windowInsets ->
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            topMargin = insets.top
        }
        WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
    }
}

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:transitionName="appbar"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="?toolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Frames.ToolbarTitle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


Change id of setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener target view to AppBarLayout, or juet add "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" to your AppBarLayout in xml,

@Kolyneh its stop changing colors, but now appbar not hidding completely and I see some of its content under the status bar

Then, add "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" to your root layout.

@Kolyneh it's not working, it just moves my bottom navbar up

OK sorry, I didn't find that you're using updateLayoutParams, change it to updatePadding instead, or just remove this setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener call.

the problem was in android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" in androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
I changed it to android:layout_height="wrap_content" and the insets worked as they should
